# Hello guys, I want the reset button of Stopwatch to be disabled at initial stage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements, stopwatch

I am trying to design a perfect stopwatch. I have tried and it is working properly. But, I want the reset button to be disabled at initial stage and when the count had begin by using start button reset should be enabled.

```
``
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './Stopwatch.css';
function Stopwatch() {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState('start');
  const [time, setTime] = useState(0);
  const [isRunning, setIsRunning] = useState(false);
  const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isRunning) {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
  }, [isRunning, intervalId]);

  function start() {
    setIsRunning(true);
    setStatus ('running');
    let startTime = Date.now() - time;
    let id = setInterval(() => {
      setTime(Date.now() - startTime);
    }, 10);
    setIntervalId(id);
  }

  function pause() {
    setStatus('paused');
    setIsRunning(false);
  }

  function resume() {
    setIsRunning(true);
    setStatus('running');
    let startTime = Date.now() - time;
    let id = setInterval(() => {
      setTime(Date.now() - startTime);
    }, 10);
    setIntervalId(id);
  }

  function reset() {
    setTime(0);
    setStatus('start');
    setIsRunning(false);
  }

  let hours = Math.floor((time / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  let minutes = Math.floor((time / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
  let seconds = Math.floor((time / 1000) % 60);


  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        <h1><b>React Stopwatch</b></h1>
        {hours < 10 ? '0' + hours : hours}:
        {minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes}:
        {seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds}
      
      </h1>
      {isRunning ?(
      <>
      <button onClick={pause}>Pause</button>
      <button onClick={reset}>Reset</button>
      </>
      ):
      (status ==='start'?(
        <>
          <button onClick={start}>Start</button>
          <button onClick={reset}>Reset</button>
        </>) : ( <>
          <button onClick={resume}>Resume</button>
          <button onClick={reset}>Reset</button>
          </>)
      ) }
    </div>
  );
}

export default Stopwatch;
`
`
```

I want the reset button to be disabled at initial stage and when the count had begin by using start button reset should be enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `disabled` attribute on the `button` wherever you want to disable it.
In your case, you can disable it when `time` is `0` when the `status` is `start`.

```
 <button onClick={reset} disabled={time === 0}>Reset</button>
```